# ASP.NET mp3 player

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for a simple mp3 control, my project is an ASP.NET web site (VS2008/C#), I've searched a lot but there was no luck, how can I give my users a small mp3 player control which enables them to pause/stop/change music? I want it to be usable in all major browsers, and of course no Silverlight as SL is still not widely supported, what are my options?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more details here is my suggestion.

You can use one of the many open source flash players available. These players can play MP3's. Flash is installed by more than 90% of all browsers. You could also use a service like HulkShare that will allow you to upload your files then give you the HTML required to embed it into your site.

Comment: thanks brownman, can you name some free flash players? have you tested one of them? I've used several flash players but nothing achieved!

Comment: Thanks again brownman, I could fix it, I found a simple mp3 player (I think it is flash based) and now it works! I had a download manager which grabbed my MP3 file and it was virtually disabling my player!